# How would I translate numbers to words in Scheme?

Tags: numbers, scheme, words

We just started with scheme at the university and I need some help doing my task.

We shall write a program that translates numbers into words, **EG: 1 to "one"**.

It must work for all numbers up to 10 ^ 9. I've got no real clue how to do this.
My basic idea would be to create some sort of array or list where I define those numbers as words like this:

```
('ZERO', 0) ('ONE', 1) ('TWO', 2) ('THREE', 3) ('FOUR', 4) ('FIVE', 5) ('SIX', 6)
('SEVEN', 7) ('EIGHT', 8) ('NINE', 9) ('TEN', 10) ('ELEVEN', 11) ('TWELVE', 12)
('THIRTEEN', 13) ('FOURTEEN', 14) ('FIFTEEN', 15) ('SIXTEEN', 16)
('SEVENTEEN', 17) ('EIGHTEEN', 18) ('NINETEEN', 19) ('TWENTY', 20) ('THIRTY', 30)
('FORTY', 40) ('FIFTY', 50) ('SIXTY', 60) ('SEVENTY', 70) ('EIGHTY', 80) 
('NINETY', 90) ('HUNDRED', 100) ('THOUSAND', 1000) ('MILLION', 1000000) 
('BILLION', 1000000000) ('TRILLION', 1000000000000) 
('QUADRILLION', 1000000000000000)
```

Then somehow check the input value with this list and substitute the numbers with the words.

But implementing this is giving me some trouble.

The main question that buggers me is if Scheme can do substrings and if I can make a list in which I define those numbers as words (so define 1 as one).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scheme, so I can only assist in the logic behind the solution. First see if you can convert a number between 0 and 999 inclusive into the word form. Then work your way to convert numbers of greater orders of magnitude. Also, it might help if you define those pairs in reverse order, i.e. (0, 'zero') (1, 'one') etc. If scheme has a dictionary structure like python does, then it will really help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- You can't "cheat" and do (define 1 one) as 1 is already defined to be a number :)
- I don't think you need to worry about substring in this problem, you are building up a string from substrings, not the opposite...

  - You do need an operation for string concatenation though. I don't remember how they do strings in scheme though...

The only "hard" problem here is that you need to encode the arbritrary rules from the english language so...

```
//pseudocode, doing things the "dumb way" tons of ifs, aka cond
define to_str n = 
    if n == 1 then "one"
    ...
    if n == 3 then "thirteen"
    ..
    if 20 <= n < 30 then
       'twenty-' concatenated to  (to_str (n - 20))
    ...
```

After you get a version like this to work you can think about abstracting the repetitive control-flow via a dictionary or association list similar to the one you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But with this system I have to define Quadrillions of numbers by hand dont I?

Comment: The problem is the english language having quadrillions of numbers :P. You just need to use roughly those numbers you listed already (for example: check out how I only have to define the "twenty-" prefix for the twenties - the last digit is handled by recursion). My main suggestion was just to first try to "hardcode" the numers and logic in before attempting to do something more soffisticated like passing the number list as a parameter...

Comment: `string-append` will concatenate two strings. Also try looking up `assq`.